# How to limit memory for a service managed by systemd

Tags: linux, systemd

I am aware of ulimit and I know how to limit memory for a process that I explicitly start, or start using a script. But in this case I have a service that is managed and launched by systemd.

How can I limit its max memory and have it killed (or even better: prevent it from memory allocation (return NULL to `malloc` / `realloc`)) when it reaches the memory usage maximum?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [manpage for `systemd.exec`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#LimitCPU=) has a list of LimitXXXX instructions and a handy table comparing them to the `ulimit` options, by way of the `setrlimit()` system call.

To limit the process's entire address space (`ulimit -v`) use `LimitAS=`.  Otherwise to limit the just the stack (`ulimit -s`) use `LimitSTACK=` or data segment (`ulimit -d`) use `LimitDATA=`

According to the `setrlimit()` manpage, these limits will cause allocating additional memory to fail.  STACK and AS will terminate the program with a sigsegv if the limit is reached and the stack needs to grow (and the program did not handle this).

Comment: Note that `setrlimit()` doesn't seem to be effective to limit amount of memory used with modern Linux kernels. You really want to use `cgroups` instead that allow much more fine-grained limits (both soft and hard) but the `Limit*` settings are not good for this. In addition, `cgroup` related options contain the whole service as a whole so you can control services that fork and run multiple children. See `cgroup` related options instead: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html

Answer (score 8):

Systemd supports limiting memory usage via the MemoryLimit option, as described at: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html

The way system handles the situation when maximum memory allowed (per service) is exhausted depends on both the underlying cgroups implementation and the way systemd implements resource control; I'm guessing the process would be killed (via OOM killer).

Comment: Would it restart the service when memory limit is reached?

Comment: @AftabNaveed It terminates the task once the memory limit is reached, then the normal rules apply for a service that exited unexpectedly.  So if you have something like `Restart=always` in the `.service` file then yes, it will restart after the memory limit has been reached.

Answer (score 4):

For limits analogous to ulimit:

```
man systemd.exec

...
LimitAS=(like ulimit -v)
...
LimitRSS=(like ulimit -m)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Since systemd `231` you can specify

```
[Service]
MemoryHigh=750M
MemoryMax=1G
```

Above `MemoryHigh` the processes are heavily slowed down and memory might be taken away. If memory usage cannot be contained under the `MemoryMax` limit, out-of-memory killer is invoked inside the unit.

It requires enabling memory accounting, e.g. in the system-wide config.

```
MemoryAccounting=yes
```

See [documentation for more details](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.resource-control.html).